# How to get "paymentState" from in-app subscription or subscription is free trail or not?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

As per [google document](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions) a paymentState -> (return integer)  The payment state of the subscription. Possible values are:

1. Payment pending -> 0
2. Payment received -> 1
3. Free trial -> 2
4. Pending deferred upgrade/downgrade -> 3

Can anybody help me get this "paymentState" field by codding?

Comment: Did you find how to get the paymentState?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this field using Google Play Developer API [Purchases.subscriptons get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get). For more information and code example learn [example projects](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples)